# amDifference not working on ionic to calculate days between dates

Tags: angularjs, date, ionic-framework, between

I am simply trying to get the difference of days between two dates

```
{{ date | amDifference : dateTo : 'days'}}
```

please help

Comment: why don't you try by making a custom filter?

Comment: any error you are getting in console ? Everything you are doing is right considering you have set correct date and dateTo variable